# Issue on Switching Highcharts.js Spider Web Chart and Column Chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working on an application which users can switch the chart type from Spider web chart to  Column Chart or Vice Versa. But As you can see from the code snippet when I change the Spider Web Type to column and disable the polar property the first column of the chart sticks to `Y` axis and so on with the last column as show in the image:

[image: Chart]

```js
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
    //  polar: true,
            type: 'column'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Budget vs spending',
            x: -80
        },

        pane: {
            size: '80%'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Development', 'Customer Support',
                    'Information Technology', 'Administration'],
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            lineWidth: 0
        },

        yAxis: {
            gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
            lineWidth: 0,
            min: 0
        },

        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
        },

        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 70,
            layout: 'vertical'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Allocated Budget',
            data: [43000, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000],
            pointPlacement: 'on'
        }]

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

I already tried to fix this by adding `offset` to `Y` axis

```
 yAxis: {
            lineWidth: 1,
            offset: 70,
            title: {
                text: 'Primary Axis'
            },
```

But it didn't do the job! can you please take a look at demo and let me know how I have to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by pointPlacement in the series:

```
pointPlacement: 'on'
```

If you remove this, the chart renders as you want.

Comment: Great thanks Steve , Is there any way we can add or remove this line of code dynamically? I mean I tried to change the `pointPlacement: 'on'` to `pointPlacement: 'off'` but this just fixed the right side of the chart and left side still in aligned with yaxix!